# Logout from all session

Tags: php, session

I have a option for logout and here is my code:

```
session_start();

session_destroy();

setcookie("key","",time()-60*60*24);

setcookie("username","",time()-60*60*24);
```

I want to add another option to logout from all session ( on another device )
for example if user change his password, all session for this user be clear and logout from all.

How can I edit all session on all devices?
Can I store session id to database, and change data with session key ? ( not current user )

Comment: if your sessions were stored in a database, along with the user's ID, you could simply delete all records (sessions) for that user's ID.

Comment: how delete session data with session key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet here would be to create your own database base [session handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php).

You will have a lot of control over what you can do with the sessions then. There is a good but dated article [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/3/7) that shows an example of how that can be done.

Comment: By the way, databases like MySQL are not created for handling sessions. They can but performance will reduce A LOT. Using something like Redis would be the best way.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a datetime field to the user table called `session_expires_at`. At every pageload, compare the current date/time with `session_expires_at`. If it's expired, log them out. When the user clicks on "logout from all session", simply set that field to `now()`.

You can not force a page to change from the server side without some heartbeat (ajax or socket.io type thing). It will have to happen on page loads.

Comment: can i store session key , and access to that session with session key later?

Comment: For that, see Orangepill's answer.

Answer (score -1):

The php has command to destroy all sessions by using the following command:

```
ini_set('session.gc_max_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
```

The first line is used to fix the session's lifetime value equal to 0 second. Then, the probability is set to 100% cleaned up.

If you need the destroy a particular user, you can add the following instructions to your session handler:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'user to delete') {
     session_destroy();
 }
```

Comment: This will end all sessions from all users. That's probably a bad thing here.

Comment: i don't want to delete all session

Comment: @Ali Akbar, I have edited my comment. you can use the second approach.

Comment: i want delete session from another device , not current session. for example in google , you have an option to log out from all device.