# PHP - Logout the all different active sessions for an user

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

If many users logged-in from different locations using same login credentials in a PHP based portal.

If any user changes the password then all logged-in users should forced to loggout and ask to login again. We can destroy the single user after password change but how to destroy all active sessions for same login id?

How to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logout from all session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031159/logout-from-all-session)

Comment: Planning to create a cookie during the login and compare it with last password change date. If password change date is greater than cookie created date then logout. Call this new function on every API call and validate.

Answer (score 1):

Step -1: Add token field in your table and whenever users register, login, logout or change password you must update token field.

Step -2: When user logs in add that token to cookie/session.

Step -3: Add check that token whenever you request to any page.